# I want to use accelerometer sensor to message saved number from my app by not launching that app

Tags: android, accelerometer

In my app I used sharedpreferences to save my friends number.
When I need to message them it needs to open my app and then shake to use accelerometer sensor, then message goes.

Here I want to send messages without lunching my app by shaking my phone.
How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. You should try a broadcast receiver with appropriate filters or a background service. There may be a better approach, just my initial thought.

BroadcastReceiver
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html
(if the action of sending takes too long, you may prefer to couple this with a wakeful broadcast receiver AND delegating the work to an Intent Service: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)

Comment: btw you might end up sending some spurious messages to your friend depending on what you do with your phone :)

Comment: I need more accurate answer .Would have been a link , sample project, specially a way to learn completely about this problem . :)